# Open Excel files using Office 97 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

Office 97 works well on Windows 10. The shortcut to EXCEL is configured with `Compatibility > Settings > Run this program as an administrator` set. You do not need to set `Compatibility mode`.

While Excel itself works fine, when I double-click any .XLS file in Windows Explorer, the Excel application is launched with an empty screen (or sometimes with a new, empty workbook). The .XLS file is NOT loaded.

There are two workarounds:

WORKAROUND 1: Open the file manually from within Excel. This is what I do for most spreadsheets and its not a major chore.

WORKAROUND 2: This only works for spreadsheets you open regularly.

- Create a shortcut to the spreadsheet
- Right-click the shortcut and choose Properties from the context menu
- Leave "Start in" pointing to the folder where the .XLS resides
- Change "Target" to "" "\"
- Example: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office\EXCEL.EXE" "C:\Important\MyContacts.xls"

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: You have two solutions.  It isn't clear what "this issue" is that you're trying to resolve.

Comment: what happens if Excel is already open & running before double-clicking on a file?

Comment: @fixer1234: Excel is launched, but the file that was double-clicked it not loaded into Excel. You have to load it in manually (using `File > Open`). Is the question unclear on this point?

Comment: @RickyTillson: If you double-click, a new instance of Excel is launched with the same problem (empty workspace). If you drag the file in via Windows Explorer nothing happens.

Comment: @Moab: Office 97 works well. It is lightning fast compared with Office 365 and far more stable. Word has no issues but I have a minor problem with opening files in Excel from Windows Explorer, for which I'm searching for a solution. Uncomplicated and no drama.

Comment: Why is the answer to your question, contained in the question body, instead of being submitted as an answer?

Comment: @Ramhound: Because these are workarounds, and not solutions? If I double-click an unknown `.XLS` file, this is not displayed as normal. I must admit to being confused. fixer1234 also thought, as you appear to, that the question contained two "solutions". Are you suggesting I should remove those workarounds from the question itself and see if anyone proposes them as solutions? Or do you think I should propose them as solutions myself, but just not accept them as answers?

Comment: Most people consider "workarounds" to actually be solutions when it comes to software as old as Excel 97.

Comment: @Ramhound: What do you suggest then? I could re-word the question to say something like "These are ways to load files, but they're inconvenient"?

Comment: @AlainD - I honestly don't believe you will receive an answer to your question on how to load Excel 97 on Windows 10.  The amount of people who must do this is extremely small, the amount of those people who are members of this community, likely consist of yourself. (just saying)

Comment: @Ramhound: Fair enough, good comment. There may be a solution out there that works for (other) older versions of Office/Excel so it might be worthwhile leaving this active, at least for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is two-fold:

1) Install office outside the %ProgramFiles% or %ProgramFiles(x86)% folders. For example: C:\Apps\Office.

2) Don't run Excel in `Administrator Mode` (see below)

- Navigate to the installation folder for Excel (eg. C:\Apps\Office)
- Right-click `excel.exe`, then `Properties`
- On the `Compatibility` tab, untick `Run this program in comptability mode` and `Run this program as administrator`

Now Office 97 works fine.